# I wanna use sscanf to get something from a string

Tags: regex, scanf, chinese-locale

The row string is Chinese,e.g. "九张".And the regular expression is "%[^张]";

Code segment：(mingw-32 ,windows10)

```
    char szTemp[64] = {0};
    sscanf("九张","%[^张]",szTemp);
    printf("szTemp = [%s]\n",szTemp);
```

```
szTemp = [綸
```

When I print szTemp's value ,it was messed up codes;
But,when I replace "九" to "一", it work.

```
    char szTemp[64] = {0};
    sscanf("九张","%[^张]",szTemp);
    printf("szTemp = [%s]\n",szTemp);
```

```
szTemp = [一]
```

My development environment is Fedora21.
Thanks

Comment: I find that , the "九"'s GB2312 code is 0xbec5 ,and "张" is 0xd5c5,  may be the 0xc5 make the mistake. 'sscanf' deal with multi-byte character may occur this problem.